# Connecting a SFML client to a C server

Tags: c++, c, sfml

I'm wondering whether (and how) I'm able to connect a client created with the **C++ SFML** to a basic **C** server.
I know transfering data is normally done using SFML's `sf::Packet` objects using the `send` and `receive` functions from the sockets.

Please note that this is a school project. The connexion isn't restricted to SFML, but the receiving server must be written in C.
The server is already functionnal, and it uses `dprintf()` to write on the C clients, so ideally I'd be able to do the same with the C++ client.

EDIT_1: `sf::Socket.send()` doesn't only support sending `sf::Packet` objects, but also `void*`. In my case, I need to send and receive strings so that's a first hypothetical solution.

Comment: Broad? The question seems specific enough, because it mentions specific functionalities. It is also tagged correctly.

Comment: SFML also has C bindings.

Comment: As you pointed out yourself, SFML can send raw array of bytes. That is all you need.

Answer (score 0):

SFML is only for C++. you need to use [CSFML](https://www.sfml-dev.org/download/csfml/) its official binding for C